# Angular , @ViewChild does not update when the value of the child component changes in constructor/ngOninit

Tags: angular, subscribe, viewchild

Below , I don't underestand why the console.log("My status :",status); not showing while the child property had change ,,,
this is my child component
in the constructor i have this

```
    @Output() public isLoged :Subject<boolean>  = new Subject();
    constructor(
    private authService :AuthService,
  ) { 
    
    authService.getLoggedStatus.subscribe(status => this.isLoged.next(status) );
    if(this.authService.isLoggedIn()){
      console.log(" -----Logged---- ");
      this.isLoged.next(true);
      this.authService.getLoggedStatus.next(true);
    }

  }
```

and my parent component.ts

```
    logged :boolean ;
  @ViewChild(LoginComponent) login:LoginComponent;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.login.isLoged.subscribe(status => this.getChildProperty(status));
  }

  getChildProperty(status) {
    this.logged = status;
    console.log("My status :",status);
  }
```

so the result in the console is just  =>
**   -----Logged---- **

but what i want is
**  -----Logged----

My status : true
**

Nb :the result shows just in case the code (in the childComp in consructor)is in a Onclock button!

Comment: You might want to check the difference between a `rxjs/Subject` and a `rxjs/BehaviorSubject`. the first one does not emit the values that came before subscribing while the other does.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i'm gonna see them

Comment: Thaaanks bro , it's solved !

Answer (score 1):

Change the output to EventEmitter instead Subject.

```
@Output() public isLoged = new EventEmitter ();
this.isLoged.emit(true);
```

And in the parent component template add the output decorator

```
<child-component (isLoged)="onLoggedIn($event)"></child-component>
```

and finally create the function in the parent class

```
onLoggedIn(isloged) {
    this.getChildProperty(isloged);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your reply, I solved my problem by adding the

> BehaviorSubject

instead of the `Subject`.